# Creating Flat Dataframe from Dataframe with Multiple Rows Containing Nulls

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a df that has five rows. I have verified that in each column, only one row is non-null (both at least and at most one row).

```
Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E | ....... | Col X

Null | Null   | Null  | Null  | S     |       
Null | Y      | Null  | Null  | Null  |   
Z    | Null   | Null  | Null  | Null  |
Null | Null   | X     | Y     | Null  |
```

I would like to create an identical df where all nulls are dropped and instead of five rows I only have one:

```
Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D | Col E | ....... | Col X

Z     | Y     | X     | Y     | S     |
```

How can that be done in Pandas?

Comment: are you sure all but one row will be null?

Comment: Positive! I verified with: "df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')" and the exact same dataframe is output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `ffill()`:

```
df = df.ffill().iloc[-1]
```

which gives you a series. If you want dataframe:

```
df.ffill().iloc[[-1]]
```

Comment: Very clever! Worked like a charm. I just accepted another answer so I need to wait 10 minutes before accepting yours but thank you very much!